# reading arrays of json objects with nlohmann c++ library

Tags: c++, arrays, json, nlohmann-json

I am ok using this syntax with the nlohmann library

```
{
 "key1": {"subKey1": "value11", 
          "subKey2": "value12"},
 "key2": {"subKey1": "value21", 
          "subKey2": "value22"}
}
```

But I have a new file, which is valid json too (I checked) and is written this way, it is made of a single array of repetitive objects. My code will require to look through those objects and check values inside them individually:

```
[
 {"key1": "value11", 
  "key2": "value12"},
 {"key1": "value21", 
  "key2": "value22"}
]
```

I used to read my json files this way:

```
  #include "json.hpp"
  
  nlohmann::json topJson;
  nlohmann::json subJson;

    if(topJson.find(to_string("key1")) != topJson.end())
    {
        subJson = topJson["key1"]; 
        entity.SetSubKeyOne(subJson["subKey1"]);
    }
```

But this won't work with my new file syntax. How can I access these repetitive objects and tell nlohmann that my objects are inside an array? More precisely, how would I be able to reach (for example) "value22" with this file syntax?

Thanks!

Comment: You can walk an `nlohmann::json` array just like you walk a regular array: use range-for, iterators, or just access by index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
std::string ss= R"(
{
    "test-data":
    [
        {
            "name": "tom",
            "age": 11
        },
        {
            "name": "jane",
            "age": 12
        }
    ]
}
)";

json myjson = json::parse(ss);

auto &students = myjson["test-data"];

for(auto &student : students) {
    cout << "name=" << student["name"].get<std::string>() << endl;
}
```